# JavaScript - Save ArrayList to variable in format manner

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist

I am trying to create an arraylist with three dates. I then want to save the arraylist into variable in a formatted way. However, when I try to document.write the variable, the elements are completely different.

```js
<script>
<% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("23-2-2016");
strList.add("24-2-2016");
strList.add("25-2-2016"); %>


var unavailableDates = [<% for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) { %><%= strList.get(i) %><%= i + 1 < strList.size() ? ",":"" %><% } %>];

document.write(unavailableDates);
</script>
```

The result I want is "23-2-2016", "24-2-2016", "25-2-2016".

However, I am getting this displayed: -1995,-1994,-1993

Comment: @NinaScholz The OP is generating javascript from a JSP, the dates are bing evaluated as expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string literals when printing javascript, otherwise your dates will be treated as arithmetic expressions (`23 - 2 - 2016 = -1995`).

```
var unavailableDates = [
    <% for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) { %>
        '<%= strList.get(i) %>'
    //  ^                     ^
        <%= i + 1 < strList.size() ? ",":"" %>
    <% } %>
];
```

Comment: I've tried this before but getting an error with everything between the two ' '. 

Error = 
Syntax error on token "'_$tag_________________$tag__________________________________$tag__'", delete this token

Comment: Another error. "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens." It is pointing to every single quote.

Comment: @abcdefg Is it your IDE? if it is your IDE, just try to execute the JSP and see the output, for example eclipse's JSP editor is crap and sees errors everywhere

Comment: hahaha. You're right. I am using Eclipse but when I run, it displays. However, can I somehow add double quotes between each date. E.g. "23-2-2016", ...

Comment: @abcdefg Absolutely! Just change the single quotes to double quotes, it will work!

Comment: I've tried changing the quotes but it's only displaying this: 23-2-2016,24-2-2016,25-2-2016

Comment: @abcdefg Try to add double quotes after the single quote: `'"<%= strList.get(i) %>"'`